# How to gain access to objects locked behind doublepointer? (C)

Tags: c, object, pointers, struct

In a homework task I must gain access to object specifics (i.e pID, Code), which are located in a structure. However, I need to link my function with the objects first (**ppObjects), but since I am dealing with a doublepointer, I seem to be having an issue.
It is worth noting that when I tried the same commands but function was PrintNewObject(HeaderC* pStruct4) it worked fine - so I am guessing it is an issue with me having to use doublepointer when dealing with pStruct4.

I have provided the code that I have tried below. While compiling it shows no error, but upon trying to print something from it, it says that obj is a nullpointer.

The function that I would like to link with ppObjects.

```
int InsertNewObject(HeaderC** pStruct4){
    HeaderC* testinH;
    for (testinH = *pStruct4; testinH != NULL; testinH = testinH->pNext)
    {
        int count = 0;
            while (count < 26) //one for every letter in the alphabet, as ppObjects is an array
            {
                Object9* obj;
                obj = (Object9*)testinH->ppObjects[count]; //the line that does not seem to properly define
                printf("%lu", obj->Code); //running this line crashes my program
                count++;
            }
    }
```

Header, where we can see that ppObjects is a doublepointer.

```
typedef struct headc
{
    void **ppObjects; // Pointer to the array of pointers to objects. 
                      // Objects may be of types Object1-10 
    char cBegin;      // The first letter of ID of objects related to
                      // header is cBegin.
    struct headc *pNext;
} HeaderC;
```

The object I was provided in the hometask is below. This is what I would get access to after defining

```
typedef struct ob9
{
    char *pID;
    unsigned long int Code;
    Date3 *pDate3; 
    struct ob9 *pNext;
} Object9;
```

I get an error saying that obj is nullpointer when I try to print anything from obj.

If this is poorly worded, I am sorry. I tried my best to make this understandable yet not too long. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is not a [mre].  Where does `ppObjects` get its value from?  How is that table of pointers initialized and assigned to?

Comment: This is not enough to demonstrate the crash